# Clockwork with Resque queueing duplicate jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque, clockwork

I'm using database events and resque to queue specific tasks, but it looks like it's enqueueing the job multiple times:

```
16:27:00 scheduler.1 | I, [2014-09-21T16:27:00.916001 #21736]  INFO -- : Triggering 'TimeSlot:6'
16:27:35 scheduler.1 | I, [2014-09-21T16:27:35.035227 #21736]  INFO -- : Triggering 'sync_database_events_for_model_TimeSlot'
16:27:36 scheduler.1 | I, [2014-09-21T16:27:36.039108 #21736]  INFO -- : Triggering 'TimeSlot:6'
```

Notice the timestamps, it queueing the job once right on the minute (the timestamp from the object) and once again right after clockwork syncs with the database.

Here is my clock.rb:

```rb
require File.expand_path('../../config/boot',        __FILE__)
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'clockwork'
require 'clockwork/database_events'
require 'clockwork/database_events/manager'

module Clockwork
  # required to enable database syncing support
  Clockwork.manager = DatabaseEvents::Manager.new

  sync_database_events model: TimeSlot, every: 1.minute do |time_slot|
    # Send emails with Resque
    time_slot.queue_reminder
  end
end
```

And time_slot.rb:

```rb
class TimeSlot < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person

  def queue_reminder
    Resque.enqueue(TimeSlotReminder, person.id, id)
  end

  def frequency
    # one week in seconds
    604800
  end

  def at
    "#{day} #{time.strftime('%H:%M')}"
  end
end
```

Thank you for looking!

Comment: Yeah — it was a bug with the gem. The developer has taken care of it, apparently.  I'm not sure if it's been pushed to rubygems though, you might want to check github. There should be an issue about this.